# Count in column B if column A=x

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016, countif

In Excel, I want to count the number of Y in column B *if* column A equals F. Does anyone know the code?

For example, in column A, I have people's gender. In column B, I have if they are pregnant or not (yes or no). I want to know the number of pregnant people *among* the females, so only if column A = female.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Hint:  COUNTIFS()

Comment: Ok. So I did =COUNTIFS(E2:E209, "F", F2:F209, "yes")                                But what if I want to see if Column F equals "yes" or "Y" ?                              Some of them have yes recorded as "yes" and some have it as "Y"

Comment: For the or use this `=SUM(COUNTIFS(E:E,"F",F:F,{"yes","y"}))` and instead of hitting enter to exit edit mode use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Free suggestion: add a _conditional format_ for the cells of the column B when the cell is not empty (or it is set to `yes`,`y`...) and the corresponding cell of the gender is not `M`, maybe changing the background colour,  just to put it in evidence.

Comment: ok. One more question. What if I want to count the number of blank cells among females? As in I want to count the number of blank cells in column F if column E is "female".                                                          All in all, I want to know the number of pregnant females (got it) number of non-pregnant females (got it) and number of females with a blank answer (How?)

Comment: The criteria for empty cells is `"<>"`

Comment: So, =SUM(COUNTIFS(E2:E209,"F",F2:F209,"<>"))   <--not working

Comment: No remove the SUM() wrapper as you are only using one criteria. then it should work.  If that does not work then you may have spaces in the field instead of a truly empty field.

Answer (score 1):

If only women can be pregnant, below your data in column B, use the follwoing formula `=countif(b2:b50,"yes")`. Replace b2 and b50 with the appropriate range of cells, and replace "yes" with the actual word or truth value of those cells you wish to count.

A slower way to accomplish pretty much the same thing would be to make a third column of the truth value of "Female and Pregnant".

In C2, type `=if(and(A2="F",b2="Pregnant"),TRUE,FALSE)`. Then, copy the formula downward. Then, below your data in column C, use the following formula

```
=countif([insert range of cells in column C to test and count],[enter the criteria, for example, TRUE]).
```

To use multiple criteria with an OR in-between, you can simply use the OR function.  The or function returns true when any of the parameters are true.

Comment: What are you hiding us when you say _"If only women can be pregnant"_? ... In that arcane mystery named conception  I maybe still missing something `:-)`

Comment: @Hastur hahaha, you're right. Nowadays though, if the data is from a survey, a respondent might enter _other_  or something else entirely for "gender" and can still be pregnant.

Comment: Yep, I just didn't resist to make the joke...  Btw a conditional format on the B column associated with the corresponding A value can spot eventual incongruity/error/special cases.